# cakephp control dropdown population from database

Tags: php, cakephp, drop-down-menu, cakephp-model

I'm trying to populate a dropdown/select tag in cakephp,fortunately I was able to populate it with the values coming from my database, 
however it displays ALL. How can I limit the population to a specific ID?

To make things clear here's what I want to achieve:

Apples:
form start
dropdown-contains only values that are associated with apples from the DB
button
form end

Currently here's how it looks like

Apples:
form start
dropdown-contains all fruits values from the DB
button
form end

Here's my current code tnx any help/suggestions is very much appreciated

Controller:

```
$fruits = $this->Model1->Model2->find('list', 
array('fields' => 
array('id', 
'fruit_name',
//'conditions' => array(''=>'')
)));
$this->set('fruitsList', $fruits);
```

View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Model1.salad_fruits_id', 
array('type' => 'select', 
'options' => $fruitsList,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have association between models between models it would be easier. Just add conditions to second model.

```
//if you don't have association between models
        $this->Model1->bindModel(array(
            'belongsTo' => array( //example binding
                'Model2' => array(
                    'className' => 'Model2',
                    'foreignKey' => 'model2_id',
                )
            )
        ));
        $fruits = $this->Model1->find('list', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Model2.name' => 'apple'
            ), 
            'fields' => array(
                'id','fruit_name',
            )
        ));
```